# Is variable identifier allowed on global replace?

Tags: javascript

When a variable is passed to a global replace function it seems to parse it as a string instead of a variable. In other words, this code isn't working quite as desired:

```
var s = "stack overflow";
var t = "o";
var r = s.replace(/t/gi,"");

//returns: sack overflow
//when should return: stack verflw
```

This replaces the `t` and not the `o`'s as desired. I've noticed some examples in regex which might be too heavy for this, and thinking this there is maybe a simple fix. I've tried `\/t\/gi` and that doesn't do much.  If anyone knows if and how this is possible, please provide the answer. Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions a good read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "/t" this refers a pattern which has some letters not objects or variables.This should be the appropriate way,

```
var s = "stack overflow";
var t = new RegExp("o", "g");
var r = s.replace(t,"");
alert(r);
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/QFUe9/)

Comment: Both solution works but this fits better with what the user was trying to do. Which was to get the result in `r` instead of having the regex as `r`

Answer (score 1):

You should use new RegExp() method:

```
var s = "stack overflow";
var t = "o";
var r = new RegExp(t,'gi');
s.replace(r,'');
```